# trying to get the Euclidean Distance through a query

Tags: sql, oracle, euclidean-distance

i keep getting missing experssion error, but i cant see what i have done wrong?

```
    DECLARE
    lat NUMBER := -28;
    lon NUMBER := 151;
    BEGIN
    SELECT
      sighting_id 
    FROM
      sightings
    ORDER BY 
      sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude, 2))

    END;
```

Comment: cheers! ive changed that and removed LIMIT(i dont actually need it). but im still getting a missing expression error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several errors in your query.

- A comma before `from`.
- The use of `long`, which is a reserved word (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm)).
- `limit` (not supported by Oracle).
- The `DESC` keyword should go after the key expression, not before.  And for distances, usually `ASC` is used, not `DESC`.
- And a PL/SQL block that has a query, but not an `INTO` clause or some other place to put the results.

Are you sure you want to use Oracle?

EDIT:

Start with a query that looks more like this:

```
WITH params as (
      SELECT -28 as lat, 151 as lon
      FROM dual
     )
SELECT s.sighting_id 
FROM params CROSS JOIN
     sightings s
ORDER BY sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude, 2))
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;  -- Note:  this is in Oracle 12c+
```

Comment: Oracle 12c introduced functionality to LIMIT..., e.g. `FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY`. (Not available in versions before 12c)

Comment: yeah sorry didn't see that comma. im used to MySQL, just messing around with oracle.

Comment: @101ldaniels . . . PL/SQL blocks are not the place to start.  Just use queries directly and doing try using variables and code blocks until you are more familiar with Oracle.

Comment: is there a way to achieve this through queries directly though?

Comment: is there any reason why it keeps saying the second param lon is invalid no matter what i call it?

Comment: @101ldaniels . . . I defined `params` but then didn't use it.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Hacker rank solution:

`SELECT ROUND(SQRT(POWER(MIN(LAT_N)-MAX(LAT_N),2) + 
 POWER(MIN(LONG_W)-MAX(LONG_W),2)),4) 
 FROM STATION;`